# GUI with Qtcreator, update the value of the texbox

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm creating a gui with Qt and I would update the value of the textbox with the value that change every step. But I don't understand why it doesn't update. could you help?

this is the code

```
#include "gui_telemanipulation.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    GUI_TeleManipulation w;
    float b = 0.1;
    char* c;
    while(true){
        b = b + 0.1;
        sprintf (c, "%f", b);
        w.joint2 = c;
        w.refresh();
        w.show();
       return a.exec();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use a text box?

Comment: You're passing an uninitialized char pointer to sprintf. You need to either declare it as an array or use operator new and ensure you allocate enough memory to hold the resulting string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have no idea what your GUI_TeleManipulation does, but your while loop will never do more than one loop. 
If you want to see an increment you should try to use a timer that runs every few millisecond incrementing the variable and refresh.